# Google MyBusinessInformation API, where are the services?

Tags: rest, google-my-business-api

I'm stuck with the [BusinessInformation API](https://developers.google.com/my-business/reference/businessinformation/rest), actually I can add custom categories and services bound to it in the Google MyBusiness interface, but I'm still trying to figure out how to do the same using the API.

So far I found the way to get all the categories [here](https://developers.google.com/my-business/reference/businessinformation/rest/v1/categories/list), but I'd like to only get the categories that are bound with my current location.
Then about the services bound to each category, I couldn't figure it out what I only got similar is that [link](https://developers.google.com/my-business/reference/rest/v4/ServiceList) but it's deprecated.

Does someone know the way to do this?

Best

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Sorry for this, actually it's OBVIOUS: those are attributes of the [Location](https://developers.google.com/my-business/reference/businessinformation/rest/v1/accounts.locations#Location) object.
I'll leave this here though, just in case that someone falls in the same trap.